# Как добавить игру в библиотеку пользователя Steam?

Tags: steam-web-api, steam

Как можно с помощью STEAM API, либо другими похожими средствами добавить игру в библиотеку пользователя ? В документации не нашел методов.

Comment: Пробовали отловить запрос?

Comment: Через браузер нельзя добавить игру в библиотеку, а через клиент STEAM без понятия как отловить.

Comment: Для таких целей существует Fiddler или его аналоги.

Comment: Спасибо, давно искал нечто это программы. Но запросов нормальных там так и нет.